# .Net Core OData Serialize DateTimes differently

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, odata

I have an OData api where we need to serialize DateTimes differently. For example, some properties need to be `yyyy-mm-dd`, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, etc.

I have read the following articles:

- [.NET Core Web API with ODATA serializing DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491157/net-core-web-api-with-odata-serializing-datetime)
- [Custom OData DateTime Serializer for .Net Core 3.1 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560042/custom-odata-datetime-serializer-for-net-core-3-1-web-api)
- [WebAPI OData Datetime serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839672/webapi-odata-datetime-serialization)

Plus a bunch of other searching online and trying different patterns but I cannot seem to get it to work. Basically all of those patterns treat all DateTimes the same. I need to be able to say if propertyName = "CalendarDate" serialize this way, if propertyName = "DateTimeIncludeSeconds" serialize that way, etc.

Any thoughts on how to conditionally set the format for DateTimes on a property by property basis in a .Net Core 3.1 OData api?

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656229/json-net-as-a-webapi-2-odata-serializer-vs-odatamediatypeformatter

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks checking it out today, will see if that can help push in the right direction